# Can't do a release upgrade from 14.04: It was not possible to authenticate some packages

Tags: do-release-upgrade

Trying to do a release upgrade on Ubuntu 14.04 with:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

I get the following error:

```
It was not possible to authenticate some packages. This may be a transient 
network problem. You may want to try again later. See below for a list of 
unauthenticated packages.

libxkbcommon-x11-0
```

What is this about? I did

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

before and deactivated all ppas. What else could I do?

Comment: You can give this a try.. http://askubuntu.com/a/426121/216503

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error authenticating some packages while upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425355/error-authenticating-some-packages-while-upgrade)

Answer (score 3):

run this command

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "[Distro]\nAllowUnauthenticated=yes" > /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d/unauth.cfg'
```

this will fix your issue

and after the upgrade run `sudo rm /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d/unauth.cfg`

Comment: Actually, you need `sudo sh -c 'printf "[Distro]\nAllowUnauthenticated=yes" > /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d/unauth.cfg'` because otherwise the redirection via `>` is not in the scope of `sudo`.

Comment: Yeah. That's correct. I didn't execute the command. So I realized it after you pointed out the correction. I have updated my answer. Up-vote my answer if possible as it will help users when they have to refer this answer.